# Почему Python не видит библиотеки aiogram_timepicker и aiogram_calendar?

Tags: python, pycharm

Почему `Python` не видит библиотеки `aiogram_timepicker` и `aiogram_calendar`? Библиотеки были установлены `poetry`, прикрепляю скрин (2 и 3 позиция). При этом другие библиотеки установились успешно, ошибок не подчёркивает.

[image: ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из специфики `PyCharm` могу предложить следующий способ решения проблемы.

`File` -> `Settings (Alt+Ctrl+S)` -> `Project:{pythonProjectName}` -> `Python Interpreter` -> `Install (символ +)` -> `введите "aiogram-calendar" и "aiogram-timepicker" поочередно` -> `Install Package`.

Подобный алгоритм можно использовать и для других библиотек, если с ними возникают трудности.

Успехов :)